# Raspberry CM4 to work with external I2S codec

Tags: raspbian, codec, pcm, i2s

I'm trying to connect a raspberry compute module 4 to a TLV320AIC3104 external audio codec with PCM.

I compiled and loaded the drivers into the kernel, and the driver appears when I run *lsmod*.

I have connected an audio box, with a headset with speaker and mic to the codec, but when I run *aplay -l*, or *arecord -l*, no devices show up.
Are they supposed to show up, or do I need to configure something first?